# cakephp ControllerTest

Tags: cakephp, testing

I'm a noob trying to write a ControllerTest for the Blog Tutorial of the cakephp book.
Completing this task, I searched for a good example, which I can adapt.
The book offers the following example:
http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/development/testing.html#testing-controllers
So I created an ArticlesController.php file in /app/Controller/ and a ArticlesControllerTest.php in /app/Test/Case/Controller/

The content of my ArticlesController.php is:

```
<?php
class ArticlesController extends ControllerTestCase {
//public $fixtures = array('app.article');

public function testIndex() {
    $result = $this->testAction('/articles/index');
    debug($result);
}

public function testIndexShort() {
    $result = $this->testAction('/articles/index/short');
    debug($result);
}

public function testIndexShortGetRenderedHtml() {
    $result = $this->testAction(
        '/articles/index/short',
        array('return' => 'contents')
    );
    debug($result);
}

public function testIndexShortGetViewVars() {
    $result = $this->testAction(
        '/articles/index/short',
        array('return' => 'vars')
    );
    debug($result);
}

public function testIndexPostData() {
    $data = array(
        'Article' => array(
            'user_id' => 1,
            'published' => 1,
            'slug' => 'new-article',
            'title' => 'New Article',
            'body' => 'New Body'
        )
    );
    $result = $this->testAction(
        '/articles/index',
        array('data' => $data, 'method' => 'post')
    );
    debug($result);
}
```

}

And the content of my ArticlesController.php is:

```
<?php
class ArticlesControllerTest extends ControllerTestCase {
    public $fixtures = array('app.article');

    public function testIndex() {
        $result = $this->testAction('/articles/index');
        debug($result);
    }

    public function testIndexShort() {
        $result = $this->testAction('/articles/index/short');
        debug($result);
    }

    public function testIndexShortGetRenderedHtml() {
        $result = $this->testAction(
           '/articles/index/short',
            array('return' => 'contents')
        );
        debug($result);
    }

    public function testIndexShortGetViewVars() {
        $result = $this->testAction(
            '/articles/index/short',
            array('return' => 'vars')
        );
        debug($result);
    }

    public function testIndexPostData() {
        $data = array(
            'Article' => array(
                'user_id' => 1,
                'published' => 1,
                'slug' => 'new-article',
                'title' => 'New Article',
                'body' => 'New Body'
            )
        );
        $result = $this->testAction(
            '/articles/index',
            array('data' => $data, 'method' => 'post')
        );
        debug($result);
    }
}
```

I copied this codes from the book and outcommented the fixtures.
Runing the test gave me the following error:

Error: Class 'AppController' not found
File: /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/cake/app/Controller/ArticlesController.php
Line: 3

Dafaq is wrong?
Thxs!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Try adding the following to the top of your ArticlesController file:

```
App::uses('AppController', 'Controller');
```

Comment: I would like but:
"Vote Up requires 15 reputation"

Comment: It would have been better if the answer was accepted :)

Comment: I came back, upvoted and accepted the answer, after I was able to :)